# Passing complex parameters with WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller and I am trying to pass complex object using FromUri attribute:

```
 public class MyController : ApiController
    {
       [HttpGet]
       public IHttpActionResult GetData()
       {
         return this.Ok();
       }

       [HttpGet]
       public IHttpActionResult GetData([FromUri] Request request)
       {
         return this.Ok();
       }
    }

    public class Request
    {
      public int Id  { get; set;}
      public string Category { get; set;}
    }
```

It is all working fine as long as I remove `GetData()` method. When I add it in I get the followin error: Multiple actions were found that match the request.

Is there a way of using both methods in the same controller?

Comment: _Why_ use both methods in the same controller? How would you differentiate between GetData(null) and GetData? The url is the same in both cases. An API that calls a different method depending on the payload instead of the URI is not the best decision.

Comment: I want to be able to call localhost/api/my which will return a list of objects  and localhot/api/my/?Id=1&Category=test which will return a single object. I know it can be done using simple parameters would like to use complex parameter in that case.

Comment: Try using [Attribute Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) to differentiate two routes

Comment: Then you need the `Index()` action, which by is called when no parameter is specified to return a list of objects